# Marklogic or MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, marklogic

I would to know which one choose MarkLogic vs MongoDB, I know its properties but in term of learning which one is more acceptable to choose? I have chosen MarkLogic but I think it's difficult to learn because it has a lot of documentation and it hasn't much comunity developers.
I have to choose one option for project our company and my boss is worried about MarkLogic's curve learning.

Help me which one choose.

Comment: I wrote the following article a few months ago: http://www.tamas.io/how-is-marklogic-different-from-mongodb/ (FYI, I do work for MarkLogic)

Comment: Instead of worrying about learning curve, i'd worry about stability, and features instead. If you are looking for a scalable enterprise worthy solution, I think MarkLogic would be a better choice. Then again, I work at MarkLogic too.. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for MarkLogic.

You mention your concern about learning how to work with MarkLogic. We have a MarkLogic University team that has excellent training resources. Take a look at their [Developer Track courses](https://www.marklogic.com/learn/university/developer-track/). These courses are free and are available with in-person, via-Internet, or self-paced formats. Once you've learned the basics, you can follow that up with [tutorials](http://developer.marklogic.com/learn), the [technical blog](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog), [On Demand videos](http://mlu.marklogic.com/ondemand/), [guides](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/getting-started/intro), and maybe a [local Meetup](http://developer.marklogic.com/meet), based on your needs. Our community may not be as big, but those who work with MarkLogic tend to be very helpful. You can post specific technical questions here on Stack Overflow.

The bigger question is what do you need from your database? For that, I'll join @Tamas in referring to his article comparing the two.

Comment: Hi @Dave Cassel, first of all thanks for all those links. I have a quick question, does something like DBRef, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs , exists in MarkLogic? DBRef basically allows reference to another collection, it doens't provide any sort of constraint, just makes life little easy.

Comment: @SamipSuwal I only know MarkLogic, but from the link you provided, dbrefs sound just like a URI in MarkLogic, which is the unique identifier for any document within a database.  Every connection or operation in MarkLogic happens in the context of a database, and every URI must be unique within the database.  Collections in MarkLogic are just metadata, so they don't affect the uniqueness of a URI.  HTH